# mysql subquery COUNT with WHERE clause confusion

Tags: mysql, subquery, mariadb, aggregate-functions

I been mashing buttons all day but cant get this query to work. I have 3 tables students, courses and enrollment table that shows which classes the students have enrolled in

The query needs to retrieve all courses having at least 2 students enrolled which is ordered by course with the greatest number of students

I worked out how to retrieve the count of enrollments per class but having trouble filtering enrollments to >= 2 students

```
-- coursetable -----------------------------

CREATE TABLE StudentTable(
studentID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
firstName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
LastName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
DOB DATE NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_studentTable PRIMARY KEY(studentID)
);

-- coursetable -----------------------

 CREATE TABLE CourseTable(
 courseID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
 courseName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
 hoursPerWeek int(11) NULL,
 startDate DATE NULL,
 CONSTRAINT pk_courseTable PRIMARY KEY(courseID)
 );

-- enrolment table --

CREATE TABLE EnrolmentTable(
    studentID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    CourseID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_enrolmentTable PRIMARY KEY(studentID, CourseID)
);
```

this is the query i can do showing enrollments of all classes but it shows one class having only 1 student enrolled. I need it to only display classes with => 2 enrollments

```
    SELECT ct.CourseName AS Course_Name, COUNT(st.studentID) AS Students_Enrolled
FROM EnrolmentTable et
INNER JOIN courseTable ct ON ct.courseID = et.courseID
INNER JOIN studentTable st ON st.studentID = et.studentID
GROUP BY et.courseID;
```

I need to use a subquery right? but not sure how

Comment: Classes are like courses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HAVING` to filter the result

```
SELECT ct.CourseName AS Course_Name, COUNT(st.studentID) AS Students_Enrolled
FROM EnrolmentTable et
INNER JOIN courseTable ct ON ct.courseID = et.courseID
INNER JOIN studentTable st ON st.studentID = et.studentID
GROUP BY et.courseID
HAVING Students_Enrolled> 1
ORDER BY Students_Enrolled DESC
```

Comment: OOOHH now i remember the having clause thanks!!! omg I was typing all sorts of gibbrish to try make it work thank you appreciated.